# Unicode in Cygwin .bashrc

Tags: unicode, cygwin

There's a script ( https://gist.github.com/matthewmccullough/48058 ) that I want to put in my Cygwin 1.7 .bashrc. It contains a few Unicode symbols, which always come as `?`. I've tried saving .bashrc as UTF-8, UTF-16 and a few other formats.

Comment: Which terminal program are you using? Have you checked that the font you are using contains the '➔' glyph (e.g. can you paste it into your terminal)?

Comment: I'm running cygwin.bat file in the root of Cygwin install folder. It seems to support Unicode symbols as `echo ➔' outputs ➔.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get question marks instead of Unicode symbols, that usually means that the font you're using doesn't have glyphs for them. So try a different one. The free DejaVu Sans Mono is known for relatively good Unicode coverage.

Comment: It seems the terminal supports Unicode symbols, it just can't parse the .bashrc I'm saving from Notepad.